# If X ∼ N(0, σ2), find the pdf of Y = |X|.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If X ∼ N(0, $σ^2$
), find the pdf of Y = |X|.

So far I have

$F_Y(y) = P(\lvert x \rvert < y) = P(-y < x < y) = F_X(y) - F_X(-y)$

but I don't know where to go from there

Comment: Hint: If $y\ge 0$, then $\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(-y\le X\le y)$.

Comment: Got up to that on my own but its dealing with the $N(0,σ^2)$ that's giving me trouble

Comment: Should have mentioned it in the post, the site values showing one's work. I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first find the cumulative distribution function of $Y$. For $y\ge 0$, we have
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(-y\le X\le y)=2\Pr(0\le X\le y).$$
But 
$$2\Pr(0\le X\le y)=2\int_0^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}\,dx.$$
To find the density when $y\gt 0$, differentiate, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. We get 
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-y^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What i was wondering is how you get that answer when you get that integral. I got to that integral but wasn't sure how to integrate $e^{-x^2/2σ^2}$. How do you get the integral of that? Did I just miss something easy?

Comment: We cannot an antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$  in terms of elementary functions. But luckily to find the density we do not have to integrate explicitly. As mentioned in the post, I used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which says that if $f$ is a nice function then $\frac{d}{dy}\int_a^y f(x)\,dx=f(y)$.

Comment: One can also find the answer by using the method of transformations. I prefer to avoid that method at first, since the logic of going through the cdf is clearer to students.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this distribution has a name: Half-normal distribution.
$$
F_Y(y) = F_X(y) - F_X(-y)\\
=F_X(y) - (1-F_X(y)) = 2F_X(y) - 1
$$
then differentiate for the pdf
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}\exp  \left( -\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2} \right), \quad y>0$$